Astro server mode - run tasks on start
I have a Astro on server mode with the node SRR adapter and using standalone mode and I would like do perform some tasks during the server start e.g. checking if environment variables has been correctly loaded.
This is my Astro config
export default defineConfig({
  output: 'server',
  adapter: node({
    mode: 'standalone',
  }),
  trailingSlash: 'always',
  integrations: [react()],
  server: {
    host: true,
  },
});

Only way I found which would work is to switch the node adapter to middleware mode, so I have access to server code, but that would require me to implement the whole server which I'd like to avoid. Are there better ways to do this?

Generally, I would just put it at the top of one of the JS modules of your server. If something's wrong, you can kill the server there like:
import stuff from './stuff'

if (error) {
  console.error(`Something wrong.\nExiting.`)
  process.exit(1)
}

export const otherStuff = ...

Specifically for env variables, see https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#experimentalenv
